# How to display even number and a multiple of 3 from arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Sorry, maybe I did not explain clearly. This is my pracitce

> input a positive integer. If the input is not positive then then your algorithm should output an error message and re-prompt the user for the input. This process should continue to loop until the input is valid. Your algorithm should then output whether or not the input is an even number and a multiple of 3. Note your solution must make appropriate use of sub modules.

I have to create a method which gets a positive number from user input, And I need to display even numbers and multiple of 3 from this ArrayList. I have written code for that but I have struggled with how to use another submodule to display this ArrayList.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;

public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> list;
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         int number = -1;
        printList(list, number );
        System.out.println("Enter number.  Enter 0 to end.");
        while (true) 
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
            number = sc.nextInt();

        while( number < 0)
        {
        System.out.print("Enter your next positive integer, or 0 to end: ");
        number = sc.nextInt();    
        }
         if (number == 0)
                break;
            list.add(number);            
        }     

    }
        public static void printList (ArrayList<Integer> list, int number)
        {
            for(int i = 0;i <= number.size(); i++)
            {
            if(i % 2 ==0 && i % 3 ==0)
            {
                 System.out.println(list(i));
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does "gets ***a*** positive number from user" have to do with rest of question? If you only ask for one number, the list is only one long and there are no even positioned or multiple of 3 positioned values in the list.

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Code doesn't compile! If the compilation error is your issue, show the compilation error in the question and ask about it.

Comment: You should use `list.size()` instead of `number.size()` in `printList(...)`. Since `list` is an object and `number` is a primitive.

Comment: Your indentation not good and also you have missed lot of curly brackets

Comment: even your `if` condition do not have bracket but have two lines. So `ist.add(number);` this will ignored.

Comment: @Blasanka if the `if` condition you specify did have brackets around both lines then `list.add(number)` would be unreachable.

Comment: Shouldn't the call to `printList()` be at the bottom of main, after the `while-loops`? It's currently at the top...

Comment: @Blasanka What are you talking about? There is only one place where curly braces could be added, and that's `if (number == 0) break;`. That's hardly a "lot", and there are certainly not two lines in that, since the `list.add(number)` comes *after* the `if` statement *(would be unreachable otherwise)*.

Comment: @Andreas yeah I get it. I thought that he wanted to add value to list if `number == 0`.

Comment: @ JonnyHenly: thank you!. I also thought it is a mistake that he did because there is lot of syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I get your problem, looks like you are not able to print the list, you should probably modify your code a little

you just have to paste printList() after the while loop.

```
while (true) 
{
    System.out.print(" ");
    number = sc.nextInt();

    while( number < 0)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter your next positive integer, or 0 to end: ");
        number = sc.nextInt();    
    }
    if (number == 0)
        break;
    list.add(number);            
}
printList(list);
```

and your printlist method is not correct, it should be like this

```
public void printlist(List<Integer> numberList){
    for(int i = 0;i <= numberList.size(); i++)
    {
        if(i % 2 ==0 && i % 3 ==0)
        {
             System.out.println(numberList.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

hope this helps!
Good luck!

Comment: Still has `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: And the `list.add()` is still wrongly placed in this solution, because `while( number < 0)` is there for error-catching, since the input should be **positive** numbers, and that check is true on **negatives** ("less than zero").

Comment: Much better! Now it deserves my +1. =)

Comment: in `printList` : `list` needs to renamed and also can still get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: If you're using java 8 : `numberList.stream().filter(i -> i % 2 == 0 && i % 3 == 0).forEach(System.out::println)` More elegant :)

Comment: yeah quite easy as well , but I dont how comfortable is QO with Java 8

Answer (score 1):

1. The printList method can be invoked from inside the loop
2. Have to check size of list, not the number.

Please see the below code helps

```
public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> list;
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int number = -1;
        System.out.println("Enter number.  Enter 0 to end.");
        while (true) {
            System.out.print(" ");
            number = sc.nextInt();

            while (number < 0) {
                System.out.print("Enter your next positive integer, or 0 to end: ");
                number = sc.nextInt();
            }
            if (number == 0) {
                sc.close();
                break;
            }
            list.add(number);
            printList(list, number); // Moved the print here.
        }

    }

    public static void printList(ArrayList<Integer> list, int number) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++) { // You have to get size on
                                                 // list.
            if (i % 2 == 0 && i % 3 == 0) { // Are you planning to check the
                                            // index or the content in the list
                                            // ?
                System.out.println(list.get(i)); // Get the number from list
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: System.out.println(list.get(i)); // Get the number from list Yes

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a program behaving like this right?

```
public class Array {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int number;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a positive integer or 0 to end: ");
            number = sc.nextInt();
            if (number > 0) { list.add(number); }
        } while (number != 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            int number = list.get(i);
            if (number % 2 == 0 && number % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.println(number);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And due to the `IndexOutOfBoundException` discussion, consider to print your numbers in a more safe and readable way like this (if you are using Java 8):

```
list.stream().filter(num -> num % 2 == 0)
             .filter(num -> num % 3 == 0)
             .forEach(System.out::println);
```